# How add buttons horizontally in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-android

I'm a beginner and trying to add 3 buttons horizontally I have added but they don't contain "match parent" like in android.

```
my code  
Row(
                       mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("Male")),
                          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("Female")),
                          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("Other")),
                        ],
                      ),
```

you can view the image
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwbvz.png)

Comment: Can you clarify your question as to whether you need three separate boxes of buttons or three buttons inside a button?

Comment: I need three separate buttons and the button's width should "match parent" like in android. I have attached an image you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each button in an `Expanded`.

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("Male"))),
    Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("Female"))),
    Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("Other"))),
  ],
);
```

Comment: I have added buttons but I need to change buttons size wrap content to match parent like in android is there any solution I don't want to give width size static.

Comment: @Rasheed You can change the flex value in the Expanded to adjust the width. Check out the doc for more info and examples https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Have Multiple solutions.

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
   
  ],
);
```

Second is.

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
  Text("Male"),
  SizedBox(width:10.0),
  Text("Male"),
  SizedBox(width:10.0),
  Text("Male")
  ],
);
```

And to solve Row Overflow Use Wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("Male")),
    TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("Female")),
    TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text("Other")),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
InkWell(
                  onTap: (){},
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 60,
                    width:  MediaQuery. of(context). size. width *  0.3,
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.redAccent)),
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Male',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: (){},
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 60,
                    width: MediaQuery. of(context). size. width * 0.3,
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.redAccent)),
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text(
                         'Female',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: (){},
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 60,
                    width: MediaQuery. of(context). size. width *0.3,
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.redAccent)),
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text(
                         'Other',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Result :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbqvs.png